# Pass an ID from one show page to another to view

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have generated two scaffolds Stock and DialyPrices.

Stocks have many daily prices and daily prices belong to stocks.

Inside each Stock show page I have a partial which pulls in that Stocks daily prices. When I create a new daily price I am doing it from the stock show page which pass the correct stock_id to the new daily price form via

```
<%= render partial: "layouts/new_daily_price", locals: {:daily_price=>DailyPrice.new(:stock_id=>@stock.id)}  %>
```

To pull the daily prices partial to the stock show page I am using:

```
<%= render partial: "layouts/daily_price", locals: {:daily_prices=>@stock.daily_prices} %>
```

Which pulls in the correct daily price for each stock.

So now I have a stock show page with stock information, daily price information for that stock and a create new daily price form.

What I would like to do is to take stock ID from the stock show page URL, `http://example.com/stocks/1` and use the ID in my daily prices show page so that I can see all daily prices related to that stock ID

Any help would be amazing as I am very stuck on this.

Thanks,
T

Answer (score 0):

You can render a collection like that (see [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render)):

**app/views/stocks/show.html.erb**

```
[...]
<ul>    
  <%= render :partial => 'daily_price', :collection => @stock.daily_prices %>
</ul>
[...]
```

**app/views/daily_price/_daily_price.html.erb**

```
<li>
  <%= daily_price.some_field %>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I gave that a go but I get a 'undefined local variable or method `daily_price'' error.

Comment: My bad, the path for the **dialy_price** partial was wrong, I fixed it. It should be ok now?

Comment: Is your `@stock` object set to something or is it **nil**?